# What is AccessKey in Power Bi which uses in PowerBI-SDK-Java

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Under Generate Token title there are accessKey in this link :

[https://github.com/m-moris/PowerBI-SDK-Java][1]

**String accessKey = "your access key from portal"**

I think this accessKey is in Azure but couldn't find it.

I found below link and created access keys but i'm not sure about this is the same accesKey that i have to use ?

https://help.bittitan.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008109327-How-do-I-get-an-access-key-for-Azure-Blob-storage-

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a deprecated embed form.
please read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding) for instructions on how to embed